# How to send data to a SOAP Web Service using Laravel & PHP

Tags: php, xml, laravel, curl, soap

I trying to send an XML vacancies to a Web Service using Laravel and I'm struggling to figure out how to connect to the web service, authorise and send the required data.

I have tried to use curl, but I am getting

> Error: "" - Code: 0

Below is my Code

```
$result // IS MY XML file

$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$URL = 'http://xxxxxx.com;

//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"xmlRequest=" . $result);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);

}
```

Another question that would be of help would be - Is there another way of sending data to a SOAP Web Service without having to use Curl?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. Take a look at the [`SoapClient` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php): 
You can use it like this:

```
$options = [
    'trace' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
];

$credentials = [
    'username' => 'username'
    'password' => 'password'
];

$header = new SoapHeader($NAMESPACE, 'AuthentificationInfo', $credentials);

$client = new SoapClient($WSDL, $options); // null for non-wsdl mode

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$params = [
    // Your parameters
];

$result = $client->GetResult($params);
// 'GetResult' being the name of the soap method

if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    error_log("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})");
}
```

There is [this](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap) library for Laravel. I tried it, then ended up writing my own wrapper.

Comment: I have tried using the laravel-soap library and I am getting an error that say **SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions>**. Any idea what might be causing this error?